# Best Flow for SPA

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openid-connect

Should I go with the current supported libraries that only provide Implicit Flow, or write my own code from scratch to handle the Code Flow?

After Doing quite a bit of research on the topic I see various different opinions on what type of flow to use when working with OAuth2.0 (OIDC).. Though recommendation seem to be changing and the support for the new recommendations don't seem to be there. Which path should I follow?

1. Code Flow without a client secret and PKCE seems to be the current "recommendation".
2. Implicit Flow seems to be the past recommendation.

After looking around I found that a lot of the Angular libraries written all mainly support only Implicit Flow.

So again the question is use the existing libraries with the old recommended implicit flow, or write our own services to handle the new secret-less code flow with PKCE?

Things to consider for my project:

1. In our app once you login for the first time you will have to select an org and based on that get a new token with new scopes.
2. We will have a main Launcher app that opens up iFrames with based on the app you select. Each launched app will also have to get new tokens.
3. Angular experience is limited but we are willing to put in the work to learn.
4. We are on quite tight deadlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current recommendation is to use **Authorization code flow with PKCE**. When OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 first came out, implicit flow was recommended for SPA. But this has changed due to security concerns. Soon there will be amendments for these specification to highlight the suggestion.

I would recommend to use [AppAuth-JS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS) as a library. It provide authorization code flow support with PKCE. It is an official Openid foundation library.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer... I am currently trying to use the library in an angular app.. it proves to be quite the hassle because of the lack of documentation... Do you have any experience in working with AppAuth with Angular by any chance?

Comment: @JoellyR well, I guess you have to rely on GitHub documentation of AppAuth-JS. Also, have a look at their sample app. I am not coming from a JS background though